# Duktape - error with for of loop when evaluating

Tags: javascript, c++, c, for-loop, duktape

With the following code duktape gives me a parse error for the for of loop.

```
string script = u8R"(var foo  = [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ]
        for (var bar of foo) {
            print(bar);
        }
    )";
    if (duk_peval_string(ctx, script.c_str()) != 0)
    {
        printf("eval failed: %s\n", duk_safe_to_string(ctx, -1));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("result is: %s\n", duk_get_string(ctx, -1));
    }
```

Is there a workaround for this? It also does this with buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to run it through BabelJS. This was due to for...of being added in Es6 which is not supported in Duktape.